# Dynamically Access Fields in Salesforce APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I am writing an APEX trigger to validate data entry on an object. I have many fields that follow a similar naming format and are all the same datatype:

```
Field 1
Field 2
etc.
Field 10
```

I want to loop through the fields and add an error if any fails validation:

```
for (i=1; i<=10; i++){
    if !validate(Object.get('Field '+String.valueOf(i)){
        \\ Here I need code that can add an error to "Field i"
    }
}
```

The problem is that Object.get(fieldname) doens't return a reference to the field itself. It returns the value in that field. I found a thread here

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091aFIAQ

that seems to try to address this question, but isn't resolved. Can anyone definitively say that this is or isn't possible in salesforce APEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. You can `addError()` to your [whole sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) but not to fields referenced dynamically. The result will  be that the error will appear on top of the page rather than on this particular field.

Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79291/how-to-use-adderror-with-a-dynamically-derived-field-name
and there's an idea to upvote: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000GoC5AAK

Comment: Well, thanks for confirming that I wasn't barking up a fruitless tree.